# Can I send data from Ionic JS Popup?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I try build android and in some page I'll make edit from popup. Example if i click input it will show popup and on popup be found input text. After input some text and click OK data from input text will be sent to server. But I don't know how to make it.

This my  **HTML**

```
<input class = "button" ng-click = "showPopup()">Add Popup Show />
```

And This my **JS**

```
$scope.showPrompt = function() {

      var promptPopup = $ionicPopup.prompt({
         title: 'Title',
         template: 'Template text',
         inputType: 'text',
         inputPlaceholder: 'Placeholder'
      });

      promptPopup.then(function(res) {
         console.log(res);
      });

   };
```

Can anybody help me to solve my problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had used ionicPopup show (hope it helps you) :

```
$scope.updateQ = function() {
    var alertpop = $ionicPopup.show({
        title: 'Quantity',
        templateUrl: 'popup-template.html',
        scope: $scope,
        buttons: [{
            text: '<p class="popup-p">Ok</p>',
            type: 'button-positive',
            onTap: function(e) {

                //window.localStorage.setItem("tmpqty",$scope.product.quantity);
                return $scope.product.quantity;
            }
        }, {
            text: '<p class="popup-p">Cancel</p>',
            type: 'popup-close',
            onTap: function(e) {
                //alert($scope.product.quantity);
                //return 'cancel button'
                $state.go('app.productdetail', { product_id: $scope.product_id }, { reload: false })
            }
        }]
    });
    alertpop.then(function(res) {
        var tmp_qty = res;
        var pid = $scope.product_id;
        var url = "" + base_url + "?callback=JSON_CALLBACK&store=1&service=updatevproducts&productid=" + pid + "&qty=" + tmp_qty + "";
        $http.jsonp(url)
            .then(function(response) {
                var stat = response.data;
                if (stat.status == "success") {

                    var successPop = $ionicPopup.alert({
                        template: 'Inventory of Product Id : ' + pid + ' updated successfully !'
                    });
                    $state.go('app.stocks');

                } else {
                    $state.go('app.productdetail', { product_id: $scope.product_id }, { reload: false });
                }
            });
    });
};
```